# Is the Amazon EC2 home folder automatically an EBS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I recently set up a new EC2 instance (t2.small) and it seems to have created an EBS to go with it. I did a quick stop start and the contents of the home folder seem to have remained intact.

Is it safe to assume that the home was automatically setup as an EBS and that my files wont be lost on stops in the future?

Comment: Yes, micro instances (t1 and t2) don't get non-EBS volumes anyway.

Answer (score 0):

"Yes, micro instances (t1 and t2) don't get non-EBS volumes anyway" –  datasage

Solved.